# How can I create a single NSIS script which will generate different installers based on an input parameter?

Tags: nsis

I have an application which has development, testing and live versions. I have a command procedure which currently creates 3 different versions of the installer, which can be installed on 3 separate computers.

What I would like to do would be to have one NSIS script which I pass in a parameter to, which will create one of the versions of the installer changing the name of the product and the installation folder. This will allow me to install all 3 versions on the same computer.

What I have tried so far is;

```
 Function .onInit
  Var /GLOBAL INSTALL_TYPE    
  ${GetOptions} $CMDLINE "/t" $INSTALL_TYPE
  ${if} $INSTALL_TYPE == ""
    StrCpy $INSTALL_TYPE "Live"
  ReadEnvStr $R0 SYSTEMDRIVE
  StrCpy $INSTDIR "$LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\MyComp\MyApp$INSTALL_TYPE\"
FunctionEnd
```

!define MUI_PRODUCT "FCDS-RECAP$INSTALL_TYPE"
OutFile "MyApp-$INSTALL_TYPEinstaller.exe"

One of the main errors I get has to do with MUI_PRODUCT and look similar to;

```
warning 6000: unknown variable/constant "INSTALL_TYPE.lnk" detected, ignoring (FullDeploymentUser.nsi:121)
warning 6000: unknown variable/constant "INSTALL_TYPE" detected, ignoring (FullDeploymentUser.nsi:124)
```

Two types of comments would be useful;

1. This is what you are doing wrong...
2. This is what you should be doing...

As always any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe show us the code for the lines with the warnings? Also, you onInit code is missing EndIf so I doubt it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

`MUI_PRODUCT` is technically not an official NSIS define, some guy just invented it and used it in a guide.

All instructions starting with ! are preprocessor instructions, those and `OutFile` and `File` cannot be controlled by `${GetOptions}` because they happen at compile time on your developer machine.

I don't really recommend this 3 in 1 installer solution, it is a bit complicated. It is much better to just create 3 different installers:

```
!ifndef APPTYPE
!error "APPTYPE not defined"
!endif

Name "MyApp ${APPTYPE}"
OutFile "MyApp ${APPTYPE} setup.exe"
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp ${APPTYPE}"

Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /r "c:\myfiles\MyApp\${APPTYPE}\*"
SectionEnd
```

and then just generate them with `makensis -DAPPTYPE=Beta myapp.nsi` etc.

If you really want this 3 in 1 style then you need to use the macros in Sections.nsh to manipulate the sections so that only one of them is visible and active. You also need to mark the install somehow (.ini file?) so that your uninstaller also knows which install type it is uninstalling.

Comment: What my thoughts are is to have the app name and install folders all appended with "INSTALL_TYPE" so that they would show up in "Programs & Features" as three distinct & different applications.

Comment: I understand that but like I said, it is much easier to generate 3 different installers from the same script rather than putting all 3 types in one installer.

Comment: I am trying to create 3 different installers/uninstallers into 3 different folders from one NSIS script. I want to pass in a variable to tell NSIS which one to build.

Comment: My example does that. The - D makensis switch creates a define used by the script. Your code checks for a parameter passed to the installer.